# Need to filter some strings elements but I get TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'str'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

So I'm using pandas to filter a csv and I need to filter three different string elements of a column, but when I use the **or (|)** I get that mistake. Any other way I can filter many strings without having to name different variables to act like one filter each? This is the code:

```
# What percentage of people with advanced education (`Bachelors`, `Masters`, or `Doctorate`) make more than 50K?
bdegree = df[(df["education"] == "Bachelors") & (df["salary"] >= "50K")].count()
mdegree = df[(df["education"] == "Masters") & (df["salary"] >= "50K")].count()
phddegree = df[(df["education"] == "Doctorate") & (df["salary"] >= "50K")].count()
all_degrees = bdegree + mdegree + phddegree
print(all_degrees)
percentaje_of_more50 = (all_degrees / df["education" == "Bachelors"|"Masters"|"Doctorate"].count())*100
print("The percentaje of people with bla bla bla is", percentaje_of_more50["education"].round(1))
```

By the way, I am working in an error in the logic on this code, so just ignore it :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`==` looks for an exact match and since no one's "education" includes the string `"Bachelors"|"Masters"|"Doctorate"`, it will return a Series of all Falses
.
You can use `isin` instead like:

```
msk = df["education"].isin(["Bachelors","Masters","Doctorate"])
```

The above will return a boolean Series, so using the `.count` method on it will just show the length of it, which is probably not something you want. So you need to use it to filter the relevant rows:

```
df[msk].count()
```

Then you can write `percentage_of_more50` as:

```
percentage_of_more50 = (all_degrees / df[msk].count())*100
```

Note that you can also derive `all_degrees` using `isin` as well:

```
all_degrees = df[df["education"].isin(["Bachelors","Masters","Doctorate"]) & (df['salary']>='50K')].count()
```

Also `df["salary"] >= "50K"` works as you intend only if all salaries are below `"99k"` otherwise you'll end up with wrong output because if you check `"100k" > "50k"` it throws up False, even though it's True. One way to get rid of this problem is to fill the "salary" column data with "0"s until each entry is a certain number of characters long using `str.zfill` like:

```
df['salary'] = df['salary'].str.zfill(5)
```

Then each entry becomes 5 characters long. For example,

```
s = pd.Series(['100k','50k']).str.zfill(5)
```

becomes:

```
0    0100k
1    0050k
dtype: object
```

Then you can make the correct comparison.